Selenium select click intercepted. Select.select_by_value()
I want to change rows number in table by selecting value in Select object. Select is obscured by google iframe. I can click "x" button for iframe, but google iframe is still there.
change_rows_el = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select[aria-label="rows per page"')
ActionChains(driver).scroll_to_element(change_rows_el)
select = Select(change_rows_el)
select.select_by_value("50")

I get
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <select> is not clickable at point (1067,951) because another element <iframe id="google_ads.." > obscures it

If I had a button I probably could do something like:
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "element-id")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Probably obscuring iframe wouldn't make a difference in this case.
Please notice that I try to use scroll_to_element, but it doesn't matter since select element is already located in a viewport.
Screenshot below (select is located under "Ads by Google"):


What's the website?

It is - https://demoqa.com/webtables

Here is one way of selecting 50 rows for that table:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1080")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.get('https://demoqa.com/webtables')
    select_table_length = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="rows per page"]'))))
    select_table_length.select_by_visible_text("50 rows")
    print('selected 50 rows')
    t.sleep(100)

I added some sleep time, to allow you to see the result. Of course you can run Chrome without a context manager as well. Selenium documentation can be found here.

Will check that, but I don't think just waiting is enough. Banner still can obscure my change rows select.

My answers are tested before posting them, @user3565923. This works.

I still get  is not clickable at point errors.
But I'm using pytest-selenium with selenium fixture and  --driver firefox

Also.. Can we have different google ads because of different locations?

There is no click() action involved. My code works as written and addresses your issue, regardless of ads displayed on page.

In my original question there is also no click() involved.
I'm using select_by_value() and you select_by_visible_text()
Seems like click() is called implicitly

There is no .click() involved in the code you posted so you must have some extra code somewhere that is causing the issue because it's not the Select usage. I've tested the code below and it's working.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

URL = "https://demoqa.com/webtables"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select'))))
select.select_by_value("50")


I'm using firefox driver. Can it matter?

Try it with Firefox and see but no, it shouldn't matter. Generally browsers behave the same.
